# How to read all csv files in multiple zip files?

Tags: python, pandas, glob, zip

I have a folder with many zip files and within those zip files are multiple csv files.
Is there any way to get all of the .csv files in one dataframe in python?
Or any way I can pass a list of zip files?

The code I am currently trying is:

```
import glob
import zipfile
import pandas as pd

for zip_file in glob.glob(r"C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\Temp\data_00-01.zip"):
    # This is just one file. There are multiple zip files in the folder
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file)
    dfs = [pd.read_csv(zf.open(f), header=None, sep=";", encoding='latin1') for f in zf.namelist()]
    df = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
    print(df)
```

This code works for one zipfile but I have about 50 zip files in the folder and I would like to read and concatenate all csv files in those zip files in one dataframe.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to get the names of all the files in the folder. See here for ways to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory

Answer (score 0):

The following code should satisfy your requirements (just edit `dir_name` according to what you need):

```py
import glob
import zipfile
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
for filename in os.listdir(dir_name):
    if filename.endswith('.zip'):
        zip_file = os.path.join(dir_name, filename)
        zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file)
        dfs += [pd.read_csv(zf.open(f), header=None, sep=";", encoding='latin1') for f in zf.namelist()]
df = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: The code still is reading just 1 zip file. Should I list the zip file names in `dfs = [] ` ? Also Where would I give path to the folder?

Comment: I replaced `os.listdir(dir_name)` with `os.listdir(r"C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\Temp")` and I am getting this error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\harsh\\AppData\\Roaming\\JetBrains\\PyCharmCE2020.2\\scratches\\data_00-01.zip'` . How would I resolve it?

Comment: Great! That works now. I see my mistake. However, now, I am getting a single column with all the values in the dataframe without a header. Is there a way to get the dataframe to format as per column header and respective values? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the current output, and the expected output?

Comment: Sure! Please find current output [here](http://wikisend.com/download/283564/Current_output.csv) and expected output file [here](http://wikisend.com/download/694092/Expected_output.csv) . The expected output is in the `"C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\Temp\data_19-20.zip"` file

Comment: Please find the entire current output file at: http://wikisend.com/download/653182/Current_output.csv

Comment: Maybe ```pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True, axis=1)``` it's what you mean for

Comment: How can I use the Expected output as an example and loop all the CSVs in the zip files as per that? Because if I include `axis=1` all the csv files are lined horizontally (in different columns and still all values in 1 column) instead of a vertical concatenation

Comment: It will be much better if you include link to all the zip files you are using so I be able to see the original data

Comment: Sure. I am sorry, I should had done this before I started. Please find the shared folder here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OdNtJKRyS09Ws_73ovhqKwjj8aftb9mm?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you figure out a way forward? I seem to be stuck here. Thanks

Comment: Your csv files don't have the same formation (some with more columns than the others), how do you want to handle this?

Comment: The expected outcome file / `data_19-20.zip` file has all the columns. How can I use that as a reference and populate all relative columns in the csv for all the respective columns in the files in the folder?